# Funcion Ajax Async no funciona correctamente

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Estimados estaría agradecido de su ayuda, tengo una función Ajax **Async: false**, funciona perfectamente, pero eh estado leyendo que dichas solicitud prontamente quedaran obsoletas o en desuso por decirlo de alguna forma, así la eh establecido en **Async: true**, pero al cambiar dicha opción, al llamar a dicha función desde otro evento, el código no se ejecuta correctamente dando error.

**Específicamente me da el siguiente error : TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')**

Adjunto la función y desde donde es llamada

```
function mostrar_imagenes(sku){
        var action = 'fetch_data';  
        var sku = sku;
        let arr;
        $.ajax({  
            url:"<?php echo $dominioRaiz;?>logica/admin/web/mostrar_imagenes.php",
            xhrFields: { withCredentials: true },
            async: true,
            method: "POST",
            crossDomain: true,
            dataType: "json",
            data:{ action:action,sku:sku},          
            success:function(data){   
                arr = data.html1
            }
        }); 
        return arr;     
    }

    $(document).on('click','#imagenes',function(){
            var fila = $(this).closest('tr')
            var sku = fila.find("td:eq(2)").text()
            $('input[name="sku_select"]').val(sku);
            var img = mostrar_imagenes(sku);
            var totalFilesCount = $('#galeria_imagenes').fileinput('getFilesCount', true);
            var preview = [];
            for(let x = 0;x < img.length;x++){
                preview.push(img[x]['downloadUrl'])
            }
            $('#galeria_imagenes').fileinput('destroy')

            $("#galeria_imagenes").fileinput({
                language: 'es',
                allowedFileExtensions: ['jpg'],
                uploadUrl: "<?php echo $dominioRaiz;?>logica/admin/web/agregar_imagenes.php",
                uploadAsync: false,
                uploadExtraData:  {'sku': sku}   ,
                deleteUrl: "/site/file-delete",
                showUpload: false, // hide upload button
                overwriteInitial: false, // append files to initial preview
                minFileCount: 1,
                maxFileCount: 5,
                browseOnZoneClick: true,
                showRemove: false,
                initialPreview: preview,
                initialPreviewAsData: true,
                initialPreviewConfig: img
            }).on("filebatchselected", function(event, files) {
                $('#galeria_imagenes').fileinput("upload");
            }).on('filebatchuploadcomplete',function(){
                var imgNew = mostrar_imagenes(sku)
                var imgCount = imgNew.length;
                if(imgCount < 3){
                    alert('A subido '+imgCount+' de 3 Imagenes minimo')
                }

            })

            $('#form_imagenes').modal('show')
        })
```

Comment: Si haces un console.log que te imprime?

Comment: si hago un console.log con async: true no devuelve nada, pero si lo hago con asyn:false devuelve una matriz con los datos solicitados

Comment: El error **reading 'length'** se refiere a que estas llamando a un valor que no tiene length, puede que sea un string o en su defecto un null.

Comment: Como comenta @Josue Vargas, el error es porque la funcion devuelve un string, y el `.length` funciona para arreglos, te recomiendo cambiar en tu ciclo `for` el `totalFilesCount.length` para que se itere en base al conteo de los archivos seleccionados. Cuentanos tu progreso!

Answer (score 1):

El problema que estás teniendo es que estás intentando coger la longitud del valor devuelto por el método mostrar_imagenes cuando todavía no has obtenido respuesta. Para evitar estos problemas con las consultas asíncronas, te recomiendo que eches un vistazo a las promesas. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve